# How can I change the font size of Tabs, the Address Bar and Pinned Bookmarks in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, accessibility

How can I change the font size of Tabs, the Address Bar and Pinned Bookmarks in Google Chrome?

The font settings in the Google Chrome settings only apply to the rendered web page. They do not apply to the font used to show Tabs, the Address Bar or the Pinned Bookmark titles.

Also, it is not operating system specific. Operating System settings only affect the font of the Chrome title bar and the text used in GDI windows, like the text entry window in Stack Overflow, for example.